# WebStorage.QuotaUpdater is deprecated. What to use instead?

Tags: android, class, deprecated

I'm migrating my old project from Eclipse to Android Studio.

Since `WebStorage.QuotaUpdater` is deprecated in API level 19, what should I use in replacement for this?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Class Overview on the [WebStorage.QuotaUpdater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebStorage.QuotaUpdater.html) page it lists two callbacks:

> [onExceededDatabaseQuota(String, String, long, long, long,WebStorage.QuotaUpdater)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html#onExceededDatabaseQuota%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20long,%20long,%20long,%20android.webkit.WebStorage.QuotaUpdater%29)

and

> [onReachedMaxAppCacheSize(long, long, WebStorage.QuotaUpdater).](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html#onReachedMaxAppCacheSize%28long,%20long,%20android.webkit.WebStorage.QuotaUpdater%29)

Looking at those methods, it says:

> This method was deprecated in API level 19.
>   This method is no longer called; **WebView now uses the HTML5 / JavaScript Quota Management API**.

It looks like you would now handle this on the Web App's side in JavaScript instead of natively in Java.

See [Chrome's Offline Storage Guide](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/offline_storage) for details.